# Prove that the limit of a sequence of constant functions is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

**Suppose that $(f_n)$ is a convergent sequence of constant functions on $D$. Prove that the limit function f is also constant; or find a counterexample.**

I feel like this is trivially true, because if we have the a single function $n$ times in a sequence, then wouldn't that entire sequence of functions converge to what that single function converges to? Is this logic correct ?

Comment: It's obvious to you but you still have to prove it.

Comment: What is $D$?$ $

Comment: You don't have a "single function $n$ times". You have a sequence of (possibly different) functions each of which is constant on $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ of real (or complex) numbers such that $f_n(x)=a_n$ for all $x\in D$. Pick a point $x_0\in D$. Then $a:=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x_0)=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists by assumption. It follows that one has $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=a$ for all $x\in D$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y \in D$. We need to prove that $f(x)=f(y)$, i.e. $\{f_n(x)\}$ and $\{f_n(y)\}$ converge to the same value. Let $f_n(x) \to L$, i.e. $\forall \varepsilon > 0: \exists N \in \Bbb N: \forall n > N: |f_n(x)-L| < \varepsilon$.

Since $f_n$ is constant for every $n$, we transform it into $\forall \varepsilon > 0: \exists N \in \Bbb N: \forall n > N: |f_n(y)-L| < \varepsilon$.

It follows that $f_n(y) \to L$ as well.